# parsing json into dictionary - omitting json constant keys

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json of the form

```
[{'key' : 'key1', 'value' : 'value1'}, {'key' : 'key2', 'value' : 'value2'}, ...]
```

and I would like to obtain a dictionary of the form

```
{'key1' : 'value1', 'key2' : 'value2'}
```

If I just did `json.load` I would end up with

```
[{u'key': u'key1', u'value': u'value1'}, {u'key': u'key2', u'value': u'value2'}]}
```

Does anybody have an idea how to omit these `key, value` entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you have is a JSON *string*, load it into a `list` first:

```
import json
data = json.load(file)     # or json.loads(json_str)
```

Next, use a *dict comp* to convert your `data` to the form you want:

```
data = [{'key' : 'key1', 'value' : 'value1'}, {'key' : 'key2', 'value' : 'value2'}]
r = {d['key'] : d['value'] for d in data} 

r
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

Once done, you can just call `json.dump` and store it in a file.

*Obligatory disclaimer*: Beware that dictionaries do not support duplicate keys (JSON strings do, iirc), so you might end up losing data if you have duplicate keys (the latter entry overwrites the former).